# How to center menu within the page instead of having it on the left

Tags: html, css, menu, centering

I have use this tool to generate the menu: https://www.cssportal.com/css3-menu-generator/
It works great except that the menu is horizontally align to the left of the page.

I have tried to wrap the content in div and use text align. I have tried to use left and margin-left
But the last menu item goes to the next row.

What I want to achieve is having the whole menu sitting in the middle of the page (horizontally).

[link text](https://jsfiddle.net/w01k75xu/)

```css
#menu-bar {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 6px 6px 4px 6px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 100%;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: solid 0px #FFFFFF;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}

#menu-bar li {
  margin: 0px 0px 8px 0px;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 4px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

#menu-bar a {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: arial;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 20px 6px 20px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

#menu-bar .active a,
#menu-bar li:hover>a {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #FA550F;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

#menu-bar:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

#menu-bar {
  display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] #menu-bar {
  display: block;
}

* html #menu-bar {
  height: 1%;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-bar">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Dan and welcome to Stack Overflow. I just checked your fiddle and all items appear in one row but aligned to the left. Perhaps your resolution or fiddle settings causes the line break. Could you describe a bit more what you want to achieve? "... except that the menu is horizontally align to the left of the page" sounds like you want it to align differently.

Answer (score 1):

I edited the CSS to achieve the result.

```
#menu-bar {
  /* display: inline-block;*/
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I changed the `#menu-bar` display property to `display: block;` and to make link inside it at the center used `text-align: center;`. But it will not enough to make the link center so I made the following edit.

```
#menu-bar li {
  margin: 0px 0px 8px 0px;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 4px;
  /**float: left;**/
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

`float:left` actually forcing the link items to left so I omitted it and make it an inline element with `display: inline-block;`.

```css
#menu-bar {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 6px 6px 4px 6px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 100%;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: solid 0px #FFFFFF;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}

#menu-bar li {
  margin: 0px 0px 8px 0px;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 4px;
  /**float: left;**/
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

#menu-bar a {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: arial;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 20px 6px 20px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

#menu-bar .active a,
#menu-bar li:hover>a {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #FA550F;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

#menu-bar:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

#menu-bar {
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

html[xmlns] #menu-bar {
  display: block;
}

* html #menu-bar {
  height: 1%;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-bar">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. For some reason the left over "  width: 95%; " was messing with the alignment.

Comment: @DanCele If this works you should accept the answer by clicking the grey `✔` tick mark. This way others can know there is a working solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should add text-align: center; to #menu-bar, remove float: left; from #menu-bar li and add display: inline-block;

The correct code:

```
#menu-bar {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 6px 6px 4px 6px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 100%;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: solid 0px #FFFFFF;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu-bar li {
  margin: 0px 0px 8px 0px;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 4px;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply on `menu-bar` CSS :

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Or :

```
left: 50%;
```

Also, add on `menu-bar li` CSS :

```
display: inline-block;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `diplay: flex` to get alignment done easily. This is a sample code

HTML

```
<div class="flex">
<ul id="menu-bar">
 <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#menu-bar {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 100%;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: solid 0px #FFFFFF;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}

#menu-bar li {
  margin: 0px 0px 8px 0px;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 4px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

#menu-bar a {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: arial;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 20px 6px 20px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
#menu-bar .active a, #menu-bar li:hover > a {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #FA550F;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

#menu-bar:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#menu-bar {
  display: inline-block;
}
  html[xmlns] #menu-bar {
  display: block;
}
* html #menu-bar {
  height: 1%;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

JS Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/SJ_KIllshot/6z483d7n/

Answer (score 0):

As option add text-align property to container:

```
    #menu-bar {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 6px 6px 4px 6px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 100%;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: solid 0px #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
    text-align: center;
}
```

and change styles of

```
#menu-bar li {
    margin: 0px 0px 8px 0px;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 4px;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just edit #menu-bar style :

```
#menu-bar {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center
}
```

screenshot :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can center inline elements horizontally, within a block-level parent element, with just:

```
.center-children {
  text-align: center;
}
```

You can center a block-level element by giving it margin-left and margin-right of auto (and it has a set width, otherwise it would be full width and wouldn't need centering). That's often done with shorthand like this:

```
.center-me {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I recommend to all this article https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/